# Running a ColorAnimation with a To value from a static class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, storyboard

I'm trying to solve a problem where I am running a ColorAnimation in a storyboard and the "To" value can only be provided by a static class.

Basically, the desired outcome is:

```
<ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:00:00" Duration="0:00:00.333"
  Storyboard.TargetName="border"
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
  To="{Binding XYZ, Source={x:Static ZZZ}}" />
```

Obviously this will crash since bindings can't be placed in a ColorAnimation's To value. I would consider making a duplicate of the static class's property in the ControlTemplate resources so that a {StaticResource} may be used instead:

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources>
  <Color x:Key="animation_to_value">{Binding ...}</Color>
</ControlTemplate.Resource>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or what the correct syntax would be.

The final solution I have considered is to insert the color resources in to App.xaml's resource dictionary at runtime in the code-behind and refactoring the storyboard to a separate resource dictionary and merging it at runtime, so the static resources are resolved after the colors have been inserted:

```
public App()
{
  this.Resources["storyboard_to_value"] = Colors.Red;
  this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(GetDictionaryWithStoryboard());
}
```

This seems overkill though. Please advise.